# Resize QToolButton with text

Tags: c++, qt, button, user-interface, interface

I have a `QToolButton` with a text using `toolButton->setText(....)`. However, the text is  truncated when the button is rendered. I have tried increasing the width of the button using `resize()` and `setFixedSize` but the text is centered and still truncated. Any ideas how to make the button follow the width of the text ?

Comment: Can you provided some sample code that reproduces your problem? It works just fine with the trivial case I tried.

Comment: Can you post the code of your example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QFontMetrics` to calculate the minimum size needed to display the whole text. The `boundingRect` method returns a `QRect` corresponding to the size of your text. You can specify flags like `Qt::AlignHCenter`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-4

You can subclass `QToolButton` and reimplement the `setText()` method to include a call to `resize()` or manage the size when you call  `setText()`.

Comment: Sounds a reasonable solution but I am having a difficulty to connect the dots what happens when I have the rectangle with the appropriate width and height how can I use that to set the tool button ?

Comment: Call the QtoolButton::setMinimumSize() method to resize your tool button using boundingRect.size(). But, you can manage only the width.

To calculate the text width: QFontMetrics::width( toolButton->text() ).

Comment: I am trying this with no luck:

    QFont font;
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    int pixelsWide = fm.width(name);

    toolButton_userName->setMaximumWidth(pixelsWide);

    toolButton_userName->setText(name);

Comment: The following also fails:    

    QFont font;
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    QRect rect = fm.boundingRect(name);

    toolButton_userName->setMaximumSize(rect.width(),rect.height());

    toolButton_userName->setText(name);

Comment: Use the font of your QToolButton for the QFontMetrics: QFontMetrics metrics( toolButton->font() ). Also, it is not setMaximumWidth() but setMinimumWidth().

Comment: I did what you said in the sizeHint of a QToolButton subclass (defined by me) and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the same `minimumSize(w,h)` and `maximumSize(w,h)` with correct values, I mean, for example:
In Design, in the property window of your button:

> width and height in geometry - 80x88, minimum and maximum must the
>   same.

It works for me in my case. And pay attention on icon size of the button, if it is.